# Is it possible to have a mechanism to use carbon dioxide as a source of oxygen in human body?

Tags: human-biology, biochemistry, molecular-biology, molecular-evolution, human-evolution

Is it possible to seperate O<sub>2</sub> from CO<sub>2</sub> and use it for energy In Human? Why Plants and not Humans can do it?

Comment: It's possible, though complicated, and I believe is done on the ISS.  I'm not really up on the exact method, but searching NASA web sites should provide info.  The problem is that it takes energy to do the separation, as explained in the answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most energy in humans is generated by reducing O<sub>2</sub> to water and CO<sub>2</sub>, using something like sugar or fat. Converting CO<sub>2</sub> into oxygen would require energy, not generate it.

Plants do have mechanisms to convert CO<sub>2</sub> into oxygen, but they use light as an extra energy input to push this energy-costing process.